# Computing the Kernel of an Epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $I$ an ideal in $R$, $\pi : R \to R/I$ the canonical projection, and let $S$ be some multiplicative subset of $R$. Define $\theta : S^{-1}R \to (\pi(S))^{-1} (R/I)$ by $\theta (r/s) = \pi(r)/\pi(s)$. Prove that $\theta$ is an epimorphism with kernel $S^{-1}I$ and hence induces a ring isomorphism $S^{-1}R/S^{-1}I \simeq (\pi(S))^{-1}(R/S)$.

I have already show that if $S$ is a multiplicative subset, then $\pi(S)$ is a multiplicative subset of $R/I$; and that $\theta$ is a well-defined epimorphism. The only step I am having trouble with is show that $\ker \theta = S^{-1} I$.

If $r/s \in \ker \theta$, then $\frac{r + I}{s+I} = \frac{I}{x + I}$ for every $x \in S$, which is to say there exists an $s_1 \in S$ such that $(s_1 + I)(I (s+I) - (r+I)(x+I)) = I$ or $rs_1 x + I = I$ for every $x \in S$. This in turn implies $rs_1 x \in I$ for every $s \in S$. From my understanding, we need to conclude that $r \in I$. I think that if $S \cap I$ weren't empty, then we would have the zero element $0+I=I$ in some denominators of the elements in $(\pi(S))^{-1}(R/I)$, so that we should assume $S \cap I = \emptyset$. Unfortunately, $I$ isn't necessarily a prime ideal so I cannot conclude that $r \in I$.

I could use a hint.

Comment: Since your expression is true for all $x$, can you find a value of $x$ that would help you show $r\in I$? I see that you have $s_1s - s_1rx = 0$, or that $s_1s = s_1rx$ (in $R/I$). Also, what is $a$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton Sorry! That's a typo. Thanks for the hint! I'll have to think about it for a few moments.

Comment: The edit makes more sense, thanks! Also, it might be more helpful to show that $S^{-1}I\subseteq\ker\theta$ first before showing $\ker\theta\subseteq S^{-1}R$ just to get a hang of moving all these parts around.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Hold on. How did you get that $s_1 s = s_1 rx$ holds for all $x \in S$? And by "in $R/I$", do you mean $s_1 s + I  = s_1 rx + I$. If so, that would imply $s_1s - s_1rx \in I$ and therefore $I \ni rs_1 x + s_1 s - s_1 rx = s_1 s$. But this implies $S \cap I \neq \emptyset$, which I believe is a contradiction. I am not sure what you're aiming at.

Comment: That’s the first line of your last paragraph — I just distributed the $s_1$. I’m not sure how you reached your contradiction. If $a+b\in I$ for any $a,b\in R$, that doesn’t necessarily imply that $a\in I$ or $b\in I$.

Comment: That's not the first line of my last paragraph. The first line says that $rs_1 x  + I = I$, and I'm not sure how you deduced from this that $s_1 s + I  = s_1 rx + I$. Also, I am not concluding that either $a \in I$ or $b \in I$ from the fact that $a+b \in I$. Rather, I am using the fact that ideals are closed under addition: if $s_1 s + I  = s_1 rx + I$ is in fact true, then it says $s_1 s - s_1 rx \in I$; and my first line says that $rs_1x \in I$, so adding the two together gives me an element in $I$--namely, the element $s_1s$ which, as I say, is a contradiction.

Comment: The second clause of that sentence, “which is to say,” is where I got that equality. I’m not sure how you showed that $rs_1x\in I$.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I thought that $(s_1 + I)(I (s+I) - (r+I)(x+I)) = I$ simplified to $rs_1x + I = I$. Are you saying that it doesn't, but rather it simplifies to $s_1s + I = s_1rx + I$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton I don't think that is right, since $I$ is shorthand for $0+I$ and so $I(s+I)= (0+I)(s+I) = 0s + I = 0+I$, where $0+I$ (which I wrote as $I$) is the additive identity on $R/I$.

Comment: Oh, I see. It simplifies to $s_1rx + I$, not $rs_1x+ I$. Sorry, somehow I didn’t see that $I$. That said, I believe you can use that fact that $s_1,s$ are not zero divisors to say, with $x=s$, that $s_1(0-r)s = 0$ in $R/I$ implies that $r\in I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $r s_1 x \in I$ and $s_1, x \in S$, then
$$
\frac{r}{s} = \frac{r s_1 x}{s s_1 x} \in S^{-1} I \, .
$$

Your mistake is assuming that if $r/s \in S^{-1}I$, then $r \in I$.  This need not be the case.  For example, let $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}R = \Z$, $P = 3\Z$, so $S = \Z \setminus 3\Z$, and $I = 6\Z$.  Then
$$
I_P = S^{-1} I = \left\{\frac{6m}{n} : m,n \in \Z, 3 \nmid n\right\} \, .
$$
Since $2 \in S$ then $\frac{3}{1} = \frac{6}{2} \in I_P$, but $3 \notin I$.